# Убрать крайние пробелы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `<input  type="text" id="firstTdVal">`.
Пользователь вводит в *поле* данные, после чего я проверяю *его* на пустоту. Если поле содержит пробелы, проверка срабатывает некорректно. Была применена функция trim(), с помощью которой нужно убрать крайние пробелы (или все пробелы, если input содержит только их). Пробовала 3 способами, все мимо:

```
$.trim($('#firstTdVal')); //1. обращаюсь к самому элементу input, думаю, это неверно, т.к. это не строка, а элемент

$.trim($('#firstTdVal').val());//2.обращаюсь к содержимому элемента, по-моему, должно работать, но нет 

$.trim($('#firstTdVal', this).val());
```

Как бы мне к строке обратиться и убрать лишние пробелы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `$.trim` не повлияет на значение в поле данных. Она возвращает *новую* строку без пробелов по краям.

```
console.log("[" + $('#firstTdVal').val() + "]");
var trimmedValue = $.trim($('#firstTdVal').val());
console.log("[" + trimmedValue + "]");

// по желанию:
$('#firstTdVal').val(trimmedValue);
```